# When will the generalist badge start being awarded?

Tags: discussion, badges

The Generalist badge description reads:

> Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of the top 40 tags.

There’s a [hidden rule](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/) about when the badge gets turned on:

> One thing the badge doesn't say, is that **there must be at least 200 questions in all 40 of the top tags before this badge is awarded to anyone**. That's why you won't see it on meta for a bit longer, or any new sites for about a year.

So far, [nobody on the main site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/generalist) has been awarded the badge.

But it seems to me that we’ve met the conditions for the badge to be awarded, and have done for a while now:

- Looking at the [tags page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags), the 40th top tag is [suggested-order], with 202 questions. The most recent question in this tag was July 8th, nearly a fortnight ago, so it’s been >200Qs for a while.
- At least three of our users (no surprises – DVK, Thaddeus and Richard) all meet the tag badge criterion. It seems like they should have been awarded this badge.

**Why hasn’t the badge been awarded yet?**

Comment: 4 x 9 doesn't equal 40.

Comment: For the record, there are 17 users who seem to qualify for the badge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Update: As of September 13th, 2015 the badges are now being awarded

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/generalist

<s>You've failed to take into account that the [tag page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags) is **9** lines long, not 10.</s>

Of the top 40 tags, only <s>37</s> 38 have over 200 questions and only <s>36</s> 37 have enough *qualifying* questions (e.g. non-wiki questions).

[image]

As to when I get my shiny new badge, based on current projections it'll probably be within the next 3 months unless we have some major push on the tags that are bubbling under.

You can keep an eye on the progress using [this data search](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/305810/waiting-for-generalist)

UPDATE: We now have 38 tags with 200 questions. Two more are required for Generalist to be offered:

[image]

Comment: …A maths student who can’t count. Oops; thanks.

Comment: Time to ask about that young-adult Stargate video game...

Comment: @JackBNimble - more futurama questions!

Comment: @Richard - you're evil

Comment: Perhaps properly tagging [star-trek-tos] questions will work: [`[star-trek] is:question -[star-trek-tos] closed:no wiki:no`](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstar-trek%5D+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bstar-trek-tos%5D+closed%3Ano+wiki%3Ano).

Answer (score 3):

> When will the generalist badge start being awarded?

Yesterday:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/generalist